# Is it legal in Spain/Europe to retain an employee until a replacement is found?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, labor-law, spain, employee

When an employee sends his resignation letter, is it legal to retain that employee indefinitely until a replacement is found? Is it legal to claim damages if he leaves?

This is for Spanish law and more broadly european law.

Comment: They have indentured servitude in Spain?

Comment: What does the contract say about notice periods? Normally, it's something between 1 and 3 months, based on how long the employee was with the company. That period is normally binding, unless the company and the employee agree otherwise.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite, I don't think so, but some people might take zero notice periods as the international norm. Europe thinks otherwise ...

Comment: In UK when there is no contract, the period of notice is by default the same as the payment frequency. That is, if paid weekly, then a week's notice is required on either side.

Comment: My question is more like, can a notice period be defined as "until a replacement is found" rather than in days/months? Does Spanish or European Law allow to do this?

Comment: It can't be a simple as that, or a company could hold on to a good employee who wants to leave indefinitely. There would have to be a time limit and/or other stipulations.

Comment: @Esteb, I don't think such an open-ended notice period would be legal, but an employee who **has signed** such a contract would be in a more complicated position than one who did not.

Comment: @WeatherVane No it's not! Statutory notice periods in the UK have nothing to do with payment frequency, but are instead based on length of employment

Comment: @motosubatsu are you confusing that with [redundancy notice](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Statutory+notice+periods)?

Comment: @WeatherVane I was referring to [this](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/section/86) - nothing in there relating to payment frequency and it applies to both redundancy and dismissal ([Gross misconduct](https://www.acas.org.uk/dismissals/dismissals-with-and-without-notice) has it's own rules of course)

Comment: @motosubatsu perhaps the law changed since I came by my understanding of it (from my father, who was an employer). The rules for employer and employee giving notice are different and for employee (the case here) 82(2) says *The notice required to be given by an employee who has been continuously employed for one month or more to terminate his contract of employment is not less than one week.* So apart from the initial month, the length of service is irrelevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah I'm not sure what the law said prior to the ERA in '96 - it may well have been what your father told you. It's worth noting that the statutory minimums are just that and may be increased (but not decreased) by a *contractual* notice period: e.g. an employer can require you to give more than a week. As for the OP's scenario it's extremely unlikely such a clause would be upheld in the UK at least.

Comment: @motosubatsu it was certainly pre-1996, more like 1980 when he told me. I think there are some essential or speciality jobs that would need a continuity of employee to cover, but the conditions would be in the contract of employment, not left to statutory terms.

Comment: It's one week if employed less than 2 years in the UK, one week per year of employment up to 12 years / 12 weeks.

Answer (score 6):

### Involuntary servitude is illegal in Spain/Europe

Has been for more than 100 years.

Once an employee resigns their only obligation is to work the contracted (or statutory) notice period or pay the employer the equivalent salary.

Comment: Do you have a source for the last part, the "or pay the equivalent" option? My understanding is that the employee is expected to work until the end of the notice period.

Comment: @o.m. There are exceptions to that. The employer typically needs to pay for the whole notice period, but he might allow (or even request) that the employee leaves immediately (e.g. if he fears that the employee might do more harm than good in the remaining time)

Comment: @PMF  o.m.'s point was that the answer says the employEE has the option to pay the equivalent salary rather than work the notice period.  I believe Dale is wrong about that.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica True, I have never heard of this. However, that doesn't make it impossible, just rare (transfer fees are very common when hiring expensive soccer players, for instance).

Comment: But if a transfer fee is payed, that is normally done by the new employer, not by the employee himself. And I think that would still require consent by the old employer to accept some payment to allow for an earlier leave.

Comment: (+1) @o.m. They might be expected to work but that can hardly be coerced. I would also nuance the “pay the employer the equivalent salary” in that liability *could* in theory be higher (if you are an executive and your failing to show up puts a big contract in jeopardy then maybe the employer can sue for damages in excess of the salary costs and force you to sell your house or something) but ultimately, if you don't show up, it becomes a civil matter and it will ulimately be settled with money.

Comment: So unless the law makes it difficult to start the new job without the agreement of your previous employer (as it does in India or the UAE), the option is always there. In practice, depending on the jurisdiction, suing might not be very practical or worth it for the employer, it's just that you won't get paid.

Answer (score 2):

In some parts of Europe ([germany](/questions/tagged/germany)), employment contracts normally contain notice periods which the employee must respect.

A default applies if nothing is specified in the employment contract:

- [§622 - Notice periods in the case of employment relationships - German Civil Code (Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch BGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2608))

It is common that employers and employees *negotiate* a cancellation agreement which reduces this period after notice has been given, but the employee has no right to do that unilaterally. The employer might well refuse to sign such a cancellation agreement unless a replacement can be found. In that case the employee must work for the remainder of the contracted period.

Comment: Regardless of the notice period, is it possible 
per law for the company to retain the employee until a replacement is found, and be sued for damages if he leaves the company without a replacement?

Comment: @Esteb in principle, if the contract says that the employee may end the employment with some notice period, let's say six weeks, then the employer cannot successfully sue the employee to compel employment for longer than six weeks after the notice is given nor for damages relating to the employee's stopping work six weeks after giving notice.  But (1) I know nothing about Spanish labor law, and (2) there may be statutory provisions concerning notice that override the notice provisions in the contract.  Furthermore, the fact that the employee would win doesn't stop the employer from suing.

Comment: You'd have to show actual damages that go beyond the fact that the employee is not working (and not getting paid).

Comment: @Esteb [§622(6) - Notice periods in the case of employment relationships - German Civil Code (Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch BGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p2625) prevents any longer period/conditions than stated in §622(2) being in the contract: *For notice of termination of employment by the employee, no longer notice period may be agreed than for notice of termination by the employer*.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Seems entirely fair.